How to call functions of a static typed language from an interpreter at runtime
I am implementing a simple interpreter in multiple languages. In doing so, I would like to be able to use built-in functions and methods of each language (i.e., make them interoperable). When implemented in Python, it could call built-in methods using getattr(). Similarly, in TypeScript, it could achieve this using Reflect. Now, I am trying to implement it in statically typed languages like Rust or Dart. How can I call built-in functions in this case?
Do I have to predefine calling expressions for all function names in the code *?
# Get the object from a name
class GlobalScope(Namespace):
    def lookup(self, name: str) -> typing.Any:
        try:
            return super().lookup(name)
        except:
            # Try to get built-in functions by their name  <- *
            try:
                if isinstance(__builtins__, dict):
                    return __builtins__[name] # cannot use statically
                else:
                    return getattr(__builtins__, name) # cannot use statically
            except KeyError:
                raise NameError(f"Name {name} is not defined")
            except:
                raise

